# jqPlot Data Label Color Pie Chart

Tags: javascript, html, jqplot

Im trying to create a theme something like in the sample:

```
temp = {
        seriesStyles: {
            seriesColors: ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo'],
            highlightColors: ['lightpink', 'lightsalmon', 'lightyellow', 'lightgreen', 'lightblue', 'mediumslateblue']
        },
        legend: {
            fontSize: '8pt'
        },
        title: {
            fontSize: '18pt'
        },
        grid: {
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(211, 233, 195)'
        }
    };

    plot3.themeEngine.newTheme('uma', temp);
    plot5.themeEngine.newTheme('uma', temp);
```

How can i change the data label color in chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the data label color for JQPlot using css.

Apply style to these class

`.jqplot-data-label` for Pie-charts

`.jqplot-point-label` for Line-charts/Bar-Charts

You can also check this link: http://www.jqplot.com/tests/point-labels.php#chart3

Hope it helps !!

Regards,
Anish

Comment: thx for ur answer i was looking for something object like in java script, but I guess it is not possible